# How to specify that a Search Input field is required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working with an asp.net mvc web application and i have a text input field to enter  a search criteria, but my question is how i can define that this field is required incase the user click on the search button. i was thinking of manually adding the following data dash attributes, to simulate how the [Required] model data annotation works .

```
<input  name="selectedUserNames" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required= "Please enter a value."  data-autocomplete-source= "@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "SecurityGroup")" />
 <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="selectedUserNames" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
<input type="submit" value="Seach" />
```

Comment: This will do the job! You can create a JS function to validate the content as well, and alert the user!

Comment: And if i have a Script , then it will work on all fields that belong to a specific class, instead of manually modifying each of the required fields?

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is not a clean solution, and it only works on the client side. You should create a SearchViewModel like below and pass it to your View:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Search { get; set; }
}
```

And, in your View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Search)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Search)
```

Answer (score 0):

as noted in previous answer, enabling only client side validation is not a complete solution. what if the client has disable javascript on their browser? then your validation want fire.

best option you have is to use DataAnnotation [Required] attribute. In your view enable client side validation.

If the client has disable javascript on browser server side validation will fire.

Comment: but as i will be passing extra information to the view using model objects , so i have to create a VieModel object that contains both the SearchModel and the Model class for all the model classes, which will take some time to develop. while adding the validation on the client will be easier. and if the user browser disable javascript, then on the worst case the search will not return any records.